# Can't embed a badge in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a certification and a badge provided by Acclaim. I want to embed it in my personal website but it's not working. here's the code they provided:

```html
<div data-iframe-width="150" data-iframe-height="270" data-share-badge-id="60615e70-6409-4752-9d77-3553a43d13d2" data-share-badge-host="https://www.youracclaim.com"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" async src="//cdn.youracclaim.com/assets/utilities/embed.js"></script>
```

but even when simply put onto an empty html:5 page, I get the error: `Loading failed for the <script> with source “file:///assets/utilities/embed.js”`.
What's the problem here? I'm not sure how Acclaim can provide a ready-to-paste script that's just simply not working, nothing shows up on the website. I'm guessing the problem is at the `src...` part, but don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're loading your page via `file:`, then protocol-relative URLs aren't going to work.  The script tag has:

```
src="//cdn.youracclaim.com/assets/utilities/embed.js"
```

This should be changed to:

```
src="https://cdn.youracclaim.com/assets/utilities/embed.js"
```

You'll find though that when you're using an actual web server, this is a non-issue.  The reason for the protocol-relative URLs is so that HTTP pages would use the HTTP version, and HTTPS would use the HTTPS version.  This method is outdated anyway.  HTTPS should be used everywhere, even if you're loading HTTPS JavaScript from an HTTP page.

Comment: I thought about the same thing, but this gives back a `Not allowed to load local resource: file://www.youracclaim.com/embedded_badge/60615e70-6409-4752-9d77-3553a43d13d2` error.

Comment: @Chris `https://cdn.youracclaim.com/assets/utilities/embed.js` loads fine for me. Make sure you're using `<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://cdn.youracclaim.com/assets/utilities/embed.js"></script>`

Comment: @j08691 thank you for pointing that out. While checking through that .js file I found that it replaces the `div` element with an `iframe`. This code is incorrect because it puts a `//` in front of the `www`. The snippet from the acclaim .js file: `src="//www.youracclaim.com/embedded_badge/'+e+`. I wonder if that's a problem on their end or I'm not understanding it. The link itself works if I manually remove the `//` at the front.

Comment: @Chris No, you're not understanding it.  As I mentioned in my answer, this is basically relative to the protocol in-use.  They've assumed you're going to use `http` or `https`.  You need to set it to `https://`, as I indicated in my answer.

Comment: @Brad I have modified it exactly as in your answer and I get the error seen in my first comment. The replaced (by the embed.js file) div has the following code: `src="//www.youracclaim.com/embedded_badge/60615e70-6409-4752-9d77-3553a43d13d2"`. I have updated my question to reflect my exact code with the badge ID, excluding the https.

Comment: @Chris Ah, got it, then you're just going to have to load your site from a web server.

Comment: @Brad yeah that's what I ended up doing. serve a modified embed.js file. It works for now until Acclaim gets back to me on my problem. thanks

Answer (score -2):

```
<div data-iframe-width="150" data-iframe-height="270" data-share-badge-id="4d10a792-b3c3-4ce2-a1b1-961332b9d222" data-share-badge-host=https://www.credly.com></div>
<script type="text/javascript" async src="//cdn.credly.com/assets/utilities/embed.js"></script>
```

Comment: You appear to have changed the domain name, the value of `data-share-badge-id`, and added quotes around the value for `data-share-badge-host`. Please add some explanation of how these changes solve the problem.